# Efficiently replace all And to AndAlso in VB.Net

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2015, replace

I have code that's been written by someone else and that is prone to `NullReferenceException` because of some conditions not using the `AndAlso` keyword.

My goal is to simply replace all those `And`'s to `AndAlso` with Visual Studio's regex finder. My knowledge of regex is intermediate but I'm struggling to build a regex that covers most cases.

Here are line cases to consider (✓ marks the ones that should replace the `And`):
`"" And ""` ✓
`foo " And "`
`'foo And`
`"foo'bar" And` ✓
`"foo" bar "" And baz` ✓
`foo "bar" baz " And qux"`
`"" And " foo " And` ✓ (1)

*(1) Note that lines with 2 valid `And`'s must also work*

I have come up with this regex: `((?:^|(?: And ))(?:[^"']*(?:"[^"]*")[^"']*)*)( And )`

It seems to do what I want but you can probably already tell that this is extremely unefficient and well it causes my VS to hang after usually 1 or 2 matches. I'm thinking it may be causing catastrophic backtracking.

**What regex could do that task efficiently ?**

Comment: Honestly, I'd be wary of doing this in an automated way, and instead want to review the code.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I'm aware that there are many cases that could be problematic, but with version control I'll have no problem reverting if anything goes bad and I'll know what went wrong. I have 30k+ lines of code and I'm not fixing one by one.

Comment: I also made sure with previous devs that no bitwise operations are done, so no need for `And` and `Or`.

Comment: That's fine. I'd still worry about cases like this: `If UsuallyFalse() And CausesImportantSideEffect() Then ... ` where suddenly the important side effect stops happening. It's not exactly good practice in the first place, but neither were the old `And` expressions. If we were confident of code quality, we wouldn't be in this mess. You can still use the find functions to target the code for review, and now your search is much easier, since a few false positives won't cause problems.

Comment: Very true, will definitely be re-running tests. Thanks for mentionning such a problematic case.

Answer (score 1):

I've have tried to come up with a simpler pattern and suggest this:

```
(?<="")( And )|(?<=")( And )(?!.*?\")
```

Check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/yJ0TWQ/1) live.